# rails + jquery calling javascript function, value returned is undefined

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I for my life cannot figure this out. I know it's some issue with the asynchronous way ajax makes calls but still cannot pin point the issue. I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#address').blur(function() {
    console.log("now processing address");
    var add = $("#address").val();
    console.log("address is: " + add);
    var refAdd = processAddress(add);
    console.log("refined addres is: " + refAdd);
  }); 
});
```

And then I have the processAddress function (thanks to another post on SO) which I'm calling. The issue is that the last statement above returns refAdd as undefined. Why is that??

```
function processAddress(address){
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  if (geocoder) {
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        //console.log(results[0].geometry.location);
        console.log(results[0].formatted_address);
        console.log("latitude is: " + results[0].geometry.location_type);
      }
      else {
        console.log("Geocoding failed: " + status);
        //formatted_address = "Geocoding failed: " + status;
        formatted_address = "failed"
      }
    });
  } 
}
```

It's pretty clear is a asynchronous issue, I can see in the order of how output is printed; refAdd should be printed last but it's not.

```
now processing address
address is: 415 N Mathilda Ave, Sunnyvale
refined addres is: undefined
415 N. Mathilda Ave, Sunnyvale, CA, USA
latitude is: ROOFTOP
```

Comment: Your processAddress method is not returning anything. Of course logging the return value displays "undefined" because it literally is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, the problem is because the function is asynchronous (how do I know that? because as you said: `logs` are written asynchronously *and* `geocoder.geocode` uses a callback). You have to use callbacks, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#address').blur(function() {
    console.log("now processing address");
    var add = $("#address").val();
    console.log("address is: " + add);

    // adding callback to call.
    processAddress(add, function(refAdd) {
      console.log("refined addres is: " + refAdd);
    });
  }); 
});
```

and in the function:

```
function processAddress(address, callback){ // <---- note the callback arg
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  if (geocoder) {
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        //console.log(results[0].geometry.location);
        console.log(results[0].formatted_address);
        console.log("latitude is: " + results[0].geometry.location_type);
        callback('TEST'); // <---- pass here the value you need
      }
      else {
        console.log("Geocoding failed: " + status);
        //formatted_address = "Geocoding failed: " + status;
        formatted_address = "failed"
        callback('TEST'); // <---- pass here the value you need
      }
    });
  } else {
    callback(); // <---- pass here for example error if you need
  }
};
```

I do not know this `geocoder` stuff, so you need to customize this to your own needs.